# parametrization length change for changing of Gauss curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

Starting with flat metric

$$ ( u \cos v, u \sin v,0) , (u,0, u\max), (v,0, v\max=2 \pi) $$

what mapping transformation enables getting Gauss curvature $+1$, in:

$$ ( u \cos v, u \sin v,f(u,v)) , (u,0, u\max), (v,0, v\max) $$

and to get Gauss curvature $-1$ in :

$$ ( u \cos v, u \sin v,g(u,v)) , (u,0, u\max), (v,0, 2 \pi) $$

using geodesic polar coordinates?

More particularly, for $K = +1$, since there is a contraction on $u$ lines and for $K=-1$ there is a dilation on them, how are circumferential lengths shown changed?

EDIT1:

I read that Beltrami dilation differential can operate continuously, but please  explain it in a way as simple as it possibly can get. That is, how to get  $K= 0.2$, $-0.156$ etc? Thanks in advance.